# How to define a vortex core without first defining a vortex?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, vortex

A common definition of a vortex is that proposed by [Robinson 1991](http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev.fl.23.010191.003125) :

> A vortex exists when instantaneous streamlines mapped onto a plane normal to the vortex core exhibits a roughly circular or spiral pattern, when viewed from a from a reference frame moving with the center of the vortex core.

As indicated in the paper this requires an a priori method of identifying vortex cores. So how can we define and therefore identify a vortex core without first defining a vortex (and therefore preventing a circular argument)?

Comment: Look up papers by Haller on vortex identification methods. It's not at all definitive or clear